# Visual Studio offline installation remove old versions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there a possibility to remove the old versions of installation packages from the layout folder of Visual Studio 2017 offline installation? This folder needs a lot of memory on my HDD.

Comment: Microsoft link (using --clean param): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#remove-older-versions-from-a-layout

Answer (score 23):

You can use the new `--clean` option. You'll need the file path(s) to catalog manifest(s) that contain those obsolete packages. You can find the catalog manifests in an `Archive` folder in the offline layout cache.

They are saved there when you update a layout. In the "Archive" folder, there is one or more `GUID` named folders, each of which contains an obsolete catalog manifest. The number of `GUID` folders should be the same as the number of updates made to your offline cache.

A few files are saved inside each `GUID` folder. The two files of most interest are a `catalog.json` file and a `version.txt` file. The `catalog.json` file is the obsolete catalog manifest you'll need to pass to the `--clean` option. The `version.txt` file contains the version of this obsolete catalog manifest. Based on the version number, you can decide whether you want to remove obsolete packages from this catalog manifest. You can do the same as you go through the other `GUID` folders. After you make the decision on the catalog(s) you want to clean, run the --clean command by supplying the files paths to these catalogs.

Examples:

```
vs_enterprise.exe --layout <layoutDir> --clean <file-path-of-catalog1> <file-path-of-catalog2> … 

vs_enterprise.exe --layout <layoutDir> --clean <file-path-of-catalog1> --clean <file-path-of-catalog2> …
```

**You can also invoke `vs_enterprise.exe` inside the `<layoutDir>.` Here's an example:**

```
c:\VS2017Layout\vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\VS2017Layout --clean c:\VS2017Layout\Archive\1cd70189-fc55-4583-8ad8-a2711e928325\Catalog.json --clean c:\VS2017Layout\Archive\d420889f-6aad-4ba4-99e4-ed7833795a10\Catalog.json
```

When you execute this command, Setup analyzes your offline cache folder to find the list of files that it will remove. You will then have a chance to review the files that are going to be deleted and confirm the deletions.

Comment: Is this a recent feature?  I only have one GUID if if I select it to be cleaned, it says a whole bunch of current files will be deleted.  I guess I'll have to download the whole thing from scratch to use this feature in future.

Comment: Yes. This is a new feature.
No. You don't have to download the whole packages again. A new folder will be created under ```Archive``` folder after any update progress. You can clear old packages using that catalog.

Comment: @Arman Is it safe after that to delete that Archive folder? I see it has only JSON files inside that folder.

Comment: @LoneWOLFs I think yes, It is safe to delete that folder after cleaning operation.

Comment: Also after each layout operation, there are a bunch of JSON files (e.g.  _Response_20170609091955_backup.json_)which are generated.  Is it ok if we get rid of these as well?

Comment: I have removed the Archive folder before updating offline layout. after 100% completion there is no Archive folder and I can see there are packages with multiple versions on layout dir. How to clean old packages now?

Answer (score 20):

I had created a small utility application for deleting old version folders from Visual Studio 2017 offline setup.

You can download the source from GitHub at https://github.com/deepak-rathi/VS2017OfflineSetupUtility

Or

Run the executable **VS2017OfflineSetupUtility.exe** from **Release** folder

https://github.com/deepak-rathi/VS2017OfflineSetupUtility/tree/master/VS2017OfflineSetupUtility/bin/Release

Comment: Nice tool, simple and easy

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I'm wondering why Microsoft as such a large company did not recognize to produce such simple, user friendly and absolutely required tool for downloading, updating and cleaning the Visual Studio after such a looooong time!?

Answer (score 11):

> After you perform layout updates to an offline cache, the layout
>   cache folder may have some obsolete packages that are no longer needed
>   by the latest Visual Studio installation. You can use the **`--clean`**
>   option to remove obsolete packages from an offline cache folder.

[Microsft Docs: How to remove older versions from a layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio#how-to-remove-older-versions-from-a-layout)

Comment: A feature that should have been in from the beginning. Guess I'll have to do a fresh, full download to start taking advantage of this.

Comment: no don't do a fresh one ... it will work fine ... I am using the same layout folder from the first version

Comment: The docs say that there should be one GUID folder under Archive for each update you've run. I've run it multiple times since first release (and the folder has doubled in size) but only have one GUID folder after the latest update. The docs aren't clear on whether this first creation is sufficient to remove all obsolete files from historical updates.

Comment: after the --layout finish the folder with the guid will be created

Comment: This doesn't remove all old versions, I could remove ~8GB after using `--clean` and could install VS without problem

Comment: I got 96 GB free space after use this way LOL, thanks